# Qt vertical menu

Tags: qt, menu

I'm trying to create a vertical menu with a Qt application that would have the following example structure:

```
    Language
      |--> Select
         |--> English
      |--> Load
    Image
      |--> Save Format
         |--> JPEG
         |--> Bitmap
      |--> JPEG Quality
         |--> Super High
         |--> High
         |--> Low
```

and so on. I'd ideally like to use `QMenuBar` to implement not only the top level menu items but all of the sub-menus as well. I would also like to make use of the signal/slots that can be used to trigger these various options. Some of the options are of the On and Off variety and being able to quickly reflect the selected choice with a checkmark or something would be ideal.

I can layout the `QMenuBar` and have it show up either on top or bottom when housed within a `QVBoxLayout`. However, what I want to do is to change its orientation from horizontal to vertical. I'm a novice when it comes to Qt programming and my searching hasn't yielded the right functions or Widget to use to gain this functionality.

All pointers and tips appreciated.

Here is an image that shows what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: menu structure]

The user has selected "sensor display" and is shown the 3 sub-options (pressure, pan & tilt, radiation) and also by default is moved over to the first option (pressure) which happens to have 2 sub-options (on, off).

The sub-menus all need to appear horizontally across as opposed to the "tree view" I've depicted in the text menu above.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I've implement a menu similar to your above image. I built it entirely in QML and integrated all of the data models, signals, and slots from C++ source code.

Check out the [RSS News Example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/demos-declarative-rssnews.html) as a starting point. In this example, they show you how to build a horizontal menu using QML.

The basics to make your above mock up is:

- You'll need to build three QML list views (Populate the lists in data models, format how each element in a list will look in a delegate)
- The logic can be written in C++ or in the QML, I'd suggest using a state based approach if your lists are going to be very long and complicated. Clicking on one list element in the first column will have to show/hide/scroll the second list and so on so forth.

You can do all the above in C++ if you connect your QML list view elements to appropriate signals and slots.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately I can't use QML for this part of application but I think this does give me an idea on how to do it. I am looking at subclassing QTreeView and using QAbstractItemModel to implement the view/model structure of displaying my data.